# No Audio with AVAudioRecord

Tags: ios, swift, avaudiorecorder

I'm trying a simple example to record audio in iOS using `AVAudoiRecorder` with Swift, I've created this class:

```
import Foundation
import AVFoundation

class AudioRecorder: NSObject, AVAudioRecorderDelegate {
    var audioRecorder: AVAudioRecorder?
    var file: URL? = nil
    
    func setupAudioSession() {
        let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
        
        do {
            try session.setCategory(.playAndRecord, mode: .default)
            try session.setActive(true)
            try session.overrideOutputAudioPort(.speaker)
            debugPrint("Listo todo")
        } catch {
            print("Error setting up audio session: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
    
    func startRecording() {
        file = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent("recording.wav")
        
        let settings: [String: Any] = [
            AVFormatIDKey: kAudioFormatLinearPCM,
            AVSampleRateKey: 44100.0,
            AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 2,
            AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey: 16,
            AVLinearPCMIsFloatKey: false,
            AVLinearPCMIsBigEndianKey: false
        ]
        
        do {
            audioRecorder = try AVAudioRecorder(url: file!, settings: settings)
            audioRecorder?.delegate = self
            audioRecorder?.prepareToRecord()
            audioRecorder?.record()
        } catch {
            print("Error starting recording: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
    
    func stopRecording() {
        audioRecorder?.stop()
    }
    
    private func getDocumentsDirectory() -> URL {
        let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
        return paths[0]
    }
    
    // MARK: AVAudioRecorderDelegate
    func audioRecorderDidFinishRecording(_ recorder: AVAudioRecorder, successfully flag: Bool) {
        if flag {
            print("Recording was successful.")
        } else {
            print("Recording failed.")
        }
    }
}
```

The view call `setupAudioSession` and when a button is pressed I call `startRecording` (and before do that I check the mic permissions with `AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().requestRecordPermission`).

When I press stop I get a `Recording was successful` message in the log from the `audioRecorderDidFinishRecording` callback. If I try to play the file using `AVAudioPlayer` I can read the file properties correctly:

```
"Playing ... Optional(\"file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/0760DB3E-440E-4898-83A6-0888EC2EA399/Documents/recording.wav\")"
"Duration: 4.180997732426304"
"Format: <AVAudioFormat 0x281ce80f0:  2 ch,  44100 Hz, Int16, interleaved>"
"Current Time: 0.0"
"Volume: 1.0"
```

But the there is not sound at all. I also setup the `NSMicrophoneUsageDescription` in the Info.plist to get access to the mic.

I've tried in Simulators and real devices and got not sound at all. Also, I've downloaded the WAV file and checked in an audio editor and the file is empty.

Any idea of what I can be missing? Looks like a really example and all the things I can find searching are very similar.

Comment: make audioRecorder var audioRecorder = AVAudioRecorder() and make sure that your URL is correct for the file you're trying to play.

Comment: "and the file is empty." Do you mean it has zero length, or it has recorded silence?

Comment: @devdchaudhary It's already a var audioRecorder in the class, not sure what you mean. The file path is correct because I can download the WAV from the app to my machine (or read it directly from Finder in the Simulator).

Comment: @RobNapier the file has N seconds recorded, but no sound. If I open it in an audio editor I see a flat line of N seconds.

Comment: I can't reproduce this, at least on simulator. I built what you've described here: https://gist.github.com/rnapier/4c23e1d4c3a92c8b7684075ca79aeaeb. I ran it on simulator, pressed Start Recording, recorded for a few seconds, and then Stop Recording. I then played the file, and it seems to have recorded fine. I would try my basic project, and if it doesn't work, indicate the precise setup. I built with Xcode 15b5, targeting iOS 16.4, iPhone 14 Simulator. I'm running on a 2021 MBP M1, macOS 13.4. (I use SoX to play, but that probably isn't the issue.)

Comment: @RobNapier no, no luck also with your code, so, looks like it's something related my setup maybe. Using your code and checking with ffmpeg I get this file:
  Duration: 00:00:04.74, bitrate: 1418 kb/s
  Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 44100 Hz, 2 channels, s16, 1411 kb/s
But this is the file "wave": https://ibb.co/0JSH0pP, just silence. I will check if upgrading Xcode works (I have 14.3 installed). The other version are the same.

Comment: Do make sure you can record with other things like QuickTime Player. (Though that kind of problem shouldn't impact both simulator and device.)

Comment: @RobNapiery yes, I can record with other apps, that's why is very frustrating that a very simple library do not work for me :/. Added a Timer to read the metered data and always I get "Peak Power: -120.0 dB". Searching is like this is the no-sound value so no clue what may be the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think I finally managed to make it work. Not 100% sure, but looks like I had some problems with the instance retention of the AVAudioRecorder and AVAudioPlayer. After be sure that the instances are not being destroyed all start to work as expected.